# Aframe color change

Tags: aframe

I want to make my sphere change color instantly instead of over a 3 second time duration Aframe animation, but every time I try it just doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <title>Wormhole</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <!--Sky-->
        <a-sky color="lightblue"></a-sky>
       <!--Worm-->
       <a-cylinder radius="0.5" height="3" rotation="0 0 90"
            color="lightpink" position="-15 1.5 0"
        animation="property: position;
        dur: 3000;
        from: -15 1.5 0;
        to: 2 1 -10;
        loop: true">
        </a-cylinder>
       
      <!--Worm2-->
      <a-cylinder radius="0.5" height="3" rotation="0 0 90"
            color="lightpink" position="15 1.5 0"
        animation="property: position;
        dur: 3000;
        from: 15 1.5 0;
        to: 2 1 -10;
        loop: true">
      </a-cylinder>
       
       <!--Wormhole-->
       <a-sphere color="gold" radius="3" position="2 1 -10" 
        animation="property: components.material.material.color; type: color;
        dur: 3000;
        from:gold; to:black;
        loop: true;
        repeat: indefinite">                 
       </a-sphere>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to make it change color from gold to black **instantly** every 3 seconds instead of changing color over a time period of 3 seconds.

*This code was created in glitch*

Comment: If you share the glitch link it will be easier to help you and suggest solutions. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you want with the animate component by itself.

In the past there was a component called aframe-animation-timeline-component that could string together sequences of animation, but it doesn't seem to be working any more.

Your best solution is probably write a custom interval timer component to emit an event to start the animation when you want it to start.

Not sure exactly what behaviour you wanted, but if you want to transition from gold to black every 3 seconds, you also need to transition black to gold as well...

Here's an example that makes an instant transition in each direction every 3 seconds.  It uses a 6 second recurring timer, and a 3 second offset on one of the two animations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    /* Custom A-Frame component
       Fires a specified event on this entity on a regular timed interval */
    AFRAME.registerComponent('interval-timer', {
      schema: {
        interval: {type: 'number'}, // interval in msecs
        eventName: {type: 'string'} // name of event to emit
      },
      init: function () {
        this.tick = AFRAME.utils.throttleTick(this.tick, this.data.interval, this);
      },
      tick: function () {
        this.el.emit(this.data.eventName)
      }
    });
    </script>
    <title>Wormhole</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <!--Sky-->
        <a-sky color="lightblue"></a-sky>

       <!--Wormhole-->
       <a-sphere color="gold" radius="3" position="2 1 -10"
        animation__1="property: components.material.material.color; type: color;
        dur: 0;
        from:gold; to:black;
        startEvents: timerPop"
        animation__2="property: components.material.material.color; type: color;
        delay: 3000;
        dur: 0;
        from:black; to:gold;
        startEvents: timerPop"
        interval-timer="interval:6000;eventName:timerPop">
       </a-sphere>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```